# How to pass a custom value to AutocompleteExtender?

Tags: ajax, autocomplete, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have this textbox and AutocompleteExtender

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtItemName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
MaxLength="300" onfocus="javascript:select();"
></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server" ID="autoComplete1" TargetControlID="txtItemName" EnableCaching="true"
ServicePath="~/AutoComplete.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
CompletionInterval="10" CompletionSetCount="15" FirstRowSelected="True" CompletionListCssClass="AutoExtender"
CompletionListItemCssClass="AutoExtenderList" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="AutoExtenderHighlight"
>
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

And the method is defined as

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{
List<string> items = new List<string>(count);
SqlCommand con = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader sdr = null;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = "proc_NewBooking";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchId", Globals.BranchID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName", prefixText.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Flag", 11);
    sdr = AppClass.ExecuteReader(cmd);
    ds = AppClass.GetData(cmd);
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        items.Add("" + sdr.GetValue(0));
    }
    sdr.Close();
    sdr.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
          // Log the message and continue  
}
return items.ToArray();
}
```

What I want is to pass a custom value, the [documentation](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) says that we can do this using `contextKey` property

So, I added this line to `AutocompleteExtender`.

```
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server" ID="autoComplete1" TargetControlID="txtItemName" EnableCaching="true"
ServicePath="~/AutoComplete.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
ContextKey="javascript:document.getElementById('drpCustomerType').value"
CompletionInterval="10" CompletionSetCount="15" FirstRowSelected="True" CompletionListCssClass="AutoExtender"
CompletionListItemCssClass="AutoExtenderList" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="AutoExtenderHighlight"
>
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

and overloaded the method to accept this as follows,

```
 public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
 {
      // custom code based on context key
 }
```

but when debugger hits it, I am not getting the value of `drpCustomerType` instead, I am getting the hardcoded string "javascript:document.getElementById('drpCustomerType').value"?

Can anyone tell me how can I pass the value of `drpCustomerType` to this method so that I can show item lists based on that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to handle `OnClientPopulating` event in JavaScript and set `contextKey` property value in handler:

```
function autoComplete1_OnClientPopulating(sender, args) {
    sender.set_contextKey(document.getElementById('drpCustomerType').value);
}


<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server" ID="autoComplete1" TargetControlID="txtItemName" EnableCaching="true"
ServicePath="~/AutoComplete.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
UseContextKey="true"
CompletionInterval="10" CompletionSetCount="15" FirstRowSelected="True" CompletionListCssClass="AutoExtender"
CompletionListItemCssClass="AutoExtenderList" 
OnClientPopulating="autoComplete1_OnClientPopulating"
CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="AutoExtenderHighlight" />
```

Comment: No its not working.  `autoComplete1_OnClientPopulating` or rather `sender.set_contextKey(document.getElementById('drpCustomerType').value);` is never hit in firebug. I even added a alert after that, but its never fired.

Comment: My bad. I was doing it in `OnClientPopulated` instead of `OnClientPopulating`. :-P  
It's working.

Answer (score 0):

```
 You can do it using Hidden Field, In Code Behind you didnot pass ContextKey anywhere
 Find the session and store it in hidden field at page load that will be your drpCustomerType 



   Do like this in WebMethod 

   [System.Web.Services.WebMethod (EnableSession=true)]

      contextkey= Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["drpCustomerType "].ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drp ", contextkey);

     @drp = Variable Declare in SP
```